# Is there a way to "shorten" a Merkle chain?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

If I have a Merkle chain of 3 items, is it possible to create a zero knowledge proof of the existance of a correct chain between hash 1 and hash 3?

Editing to clarify (Thanks Ricky), what I mean my a Merkle chain is:

```
   hash(foo)      = A1
-> hash(bar + A1) = B2
-> hash(baz + B2) = C3
```

An ordered set where you cannot replace any element without affecting the hash of the last element. To verify that it's correct you need to have all the data that the last hash depends on, I'm wondering if there's a way to prove that it's correct *without* having all the middle data.

Comment: What is "a Merkle chain of 3 items"? $\;$